# PREVENT initramfs from using /etc/default/keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, initramfs

A recent kernel update caused new initramfs files to be generated, and now my Ubuntu 18.04 machine is using my custom keyboard layout for the LUKS decryption password, instead of QWERTY, which it formerly used. Is there a way to prevent initramfs from using the key layout instructions in /etc/default/keyboard ?

Comment: Maybe a simpler approach would be to have the system releated settings in `/etc/default/keyboard`, and not sync it with your custom layout you (supposedly) use for the desktop. I come to think of [bug #1762952](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1762952) which I struggled with a while ago.

Comment: That would be an option, but I like having the custom layout as default at the login screen. The reason I don't want it to be the default when I enter the LUKS password is because at that point there is no icon indicating that a non-standard input is being used, leading to potential confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a keymap manually into your initramfs.

1. (optional) Choose a custom keyboard. For example "us" to load the standard us keyboard.

   sudo loadkeys (YourKeyboardName)
2. Verify the keyboard is correct, by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 and typing
3. Append the following to one of your hooks files, so that initramfs knows where to look. The hooks files are in: /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks

   dumpkeys > "${DESTDIR}"/etc/kmap

   (make sure this goes before the exit 0 line!)
4. Append the following to one of your initramfs scripts in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top

   loadkeys /etc/kmap
5. Update the initramfs. Be sure to use -c to create a new one!

   update-initramfs -c

If you don't feel like messing with the existing scripts in the initramfs-tools folders, you can always just add your own, just make sure to add the header at the top of each script and make sure each one is executable with chmod +x